# Python - Log all HTTP(s) Requests

Tags: python

So, I want to know how I could log all HTTP(s) requests without the need to use proxy to route traffic through using Python.

For example: Firefox connects to https://google.com/ and sends a post data of "hello=world" - without having Firefox forced into a Python proxy, is it possible to just monitor the data and log it (including post data), along with headers and store it to a local file?

In theory I want it so as soon as I go to google with the post data, it'll log the request I sent and store to a local file, and it'll still complete the connection without issue/proxy interception (using a linux computer - debian).

Comment: Maybe something for requests?

Comment: I was thinking something like wireshark does, it logs all the data, but doing it in python without the need for a program like wireshark, a windows program that does similar is Fiddler.

Comment: I'm not sure if wireshark does this, but I know for a fact that Fiddler uses a proxy to view traffic.

Comment: I know fiddler does, would it be possible then to maybe bind it as a system proxy forcing everything to go through it without needing to manually insert proxy settings into firefox/other browsers? I'm only interested in HTTP get/post requests.